# Issue with styled-components in "custom" single page application

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm currently working on an old project, which has its "own way" of doing a single page application (does Ajax calls to an MVC application, gets the view, replaces the view client-side, appends styles and lots of other stuff!!), and although not ideal, currently I'm stuck with it!

I am trying to integrate an existing React application into this site, and what I'm doing is to use `create-react-app` and then `build` to create the bundles, and in the application, in the view begin returned from the server for a specific page, I'm putting `script` and `link` tags, pointing to my bundle files. It's worth noting that this server view is a partial ASP.NET MVC view, so my `script` and `link` tags are somehow part of the `body`.

I'm also using [styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com/) in my React application.

Now, here's the problem: when I first load the page I mentioned, my `script` is loaded, and I can see all my components being styled properly, but when I navigate in the existing custom SPA application, at some point, styles related to `styled-components` are messed up, and the only way to get them back is to reload the page.

I was inspecting the page, and I saw that `styled-components` is doing things with a custom `link` created in the `head`, and I see `data-styled-components` attribute being populated with custom class names as my components are loaded, but when the problem arises, in Chrome Developer Tools, I see that the `link` tag flashes as if it's changed, but it stays the same.

I have attached a GIF of the tag:
- It starts with the initial page load
- I navigate away and come back and I see more classes being appended
- I repeat the step, and I only see that it flashes

I know the post is already long, but any help is deeply appreciated. Is it possible that, with the current infrastructure, it has something to do with the fact that whenever I come back to the page, a `script` tag is sent from the server pointing to my React bundle?

[image: Screen capture of the tag used by <code>styled-components</code>]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Max Stoiber for answering in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/1549):

The reason for this behavior is exactly what I mentioned at the end of the question: every time the page is loaded, a `script` tag is sent from the server, containing the bundle, which in turn causes a new instance of `styled-components` to be created; this is not supported in `styled-components`, and that was the issue